# How do I set a DataGridView to show only rows containing a specific value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This one is pretty simple but, I'll go into detail. I need to make a dataGridView filter the contents of the database table it's referencing to only show rows where the "TechID" column is a specific value I'm feeding to it from another variable. Actually obtaining that value has not been an issue, but I'm unclear as to how I'd even start to filter the DataGridView.

Please hurry, this is for a project due this week.

Edit: I've tried plugging this one into google a few times already and can only find results that work off of row indexes, which is not what I'm looking for. I need to filter by a value within the rows themselves.

Second Edit: the DataGridView is populated using a DataTable from a database as a source. I connected it to this table via the properties winddow in visual studio if that makes any difference.

Edit: Ok, so I didn't post the code I had before because I knew it wasn't correct, but since you asked, here you go:

````
        {//techValue is the ID of the technician of the row selected in dataGridView1. If I hide the TechID column, it no longer works.
            
                int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];
                int techValue = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells["TechID"].Value);
            //This hides the rows that don't share a TechID value with the selected row in the dataGridView1.
                /*int techValue2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Cells["TechID"].Value);*/
            

            
        }```
````

Comment: Typically, if you use a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid (which it sounds like you do) … then you would filter the `DataTable` by creating a `DataView` then filter the `DataView`. Bottom line is that “how” you filter the grid will depend a lot on how it is filled with data. More info is needed in relation to how the grid is filled to provide an answer.

Comment: Oh, ok. Yes, the DataGridView is populated using a DataTable from a database as a source. I connected it to this table via the properties winddow in visual studio if that makes any difference.

Comment: What do you mean by filtering? You can draw a simple schematic diagram. Show your data table by the way.